# Spring java set id property to start increment from a six digit number

Tags: spring, persistence, bean-validation

I am new to the Spring framework. In my current project, I have a property of a class that requires the ID to have a minimum of six digits in length. 
All the id's must have six digits or more. 
I have tried to set the length of the Id to be six digits below.

```
@Length(min=6)
private Long Id;
```

However, it did not work. I got the following error

> Error during managed flush [HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.Long'. Check configuration for 'HAWB']

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `Length` annotation is for `String`s. Try

```
@Min(100000)
private Long Id;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

As per hibernate documentation which I found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.html), `@Length` is used for strings and not long or int data types.
`@Min` can be used for your requirement as per [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html).